# How to write a LaTeX header

Tags: latex

I am using IEEETrans.cls to format my paper.  Now I need to add the name of the conference at the right hand corner of each page.

Can someone advise me how to do that?

Comment: You can find an entire community on the [TeX StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/), where no TeX-related question is too small.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the most comprehensive way to format headers and footers is the [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) package.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{THX 1138}
```

You may need to look up the documentation for getting the rest of the headers and footers like you want.

Comment: I'll just add link to fancyhdr manual: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem preparing camera ready version for a conference. The instructions were to put

1. centered conference name header in all pages
2. proceedings id and IEEE copyright on title page footer left
3. page number as center footer in all remaining pages

The latex code I used derived from Michael Shell's [website](http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/) is shown below. Put it just above your \begin{document}

```
\newcommand{\MYfooter}{\smash{
\hfil\parbox[t][\height][t]{\textwidth}{\centering
\thepage}\hfil\hbox{}}}

\makeatletter

% normal pages
\def\ps@headings{%
\def\@oddhead{\parbox[t][\height][t]{\textwidth}{\centering
14-th IEEE International Conference on Your conference\\
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
}\hfil\hbox{}}%

\def\@evenhead{\parbox[t][\height][t]{\textwidth}{\centering
14-th IEEE International Conference on Peer-to-Peer Computing\\
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
}\hfil\hbox{}}%

\def\@oddfoot{\MYfooter}%
\def\@evenfoot{\MYfooter}}

% title page
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
\def\@oddhead{\parbox[t][\height][t]{\textwidth}{\centering
14-th IEEE International Conference on Your conference\\
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
}\hfil\hbox{}}%
\def\@evenhead{\scriptsize\thepage \hfil \leftmark\mbox{}}%
\def\@oddfoot{ 123-123-123-123/14/\$31.00 \textcopyright 2014 IEEE \hfil 
\leftmark\mbox{}}%
\def\@evenfoot{\MYfooter}}

\makeatother
% make changes take effect
\pagestyle{headings}
% adjust as needed
\addtolength{\footskip}{0\baselineskip}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-1\baselineskip}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `fancyhdr` package to do that. See [this blog post for example](http://texblog.wordpress.com/2007/11/07/headerfooter-in-latex-with-fancyhdr/). You can add `\fancyfoot[R]{Conference name}` to the source.

Answer (score 0):

The author of the `IEEEtran` collection maintains a comprehensive FAQ section on his [website](http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/), including how to disable and customize the headers and footers.